# How can I understand these puzzling sentences?

Tags: meaning

1. Art is **I**; science is **we**.
2. We are never **beneath hope while above hell**; nor **above hope while beneath heaven**.
3. Summer is **every man a king** and **every woman a queen**.
4. I am not at a loss for **a word**; Pitt is never at a loss for **the word**.
5. Barring some piece of luck I have seen but few men get rich rapidly except by means that would make them **writhe to have known in public**.

I am totally bewildered by the sentences above. I just can't figure out what these expressions really mean. I would be grateful if someone could tell me the meanings of these sentences or paraphrase them to be easily comprehensible.

Comment: They're supposed to provoke thought, and are apt to be interpreted differently by different people.

Comment: Can you please include the source for these sentences?  (Otherwise, it's plagiarism!)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Don't get me started.  It's not plagiarism unless there's an attempt to represent others' words as your own, which Jarl clearly is not doing.  Few people are "totally bewildered" by their own words.

Comment: Ha, that was my thought too, @deadrat - although... :-)  Still, if they're not Jarl's words, the source should be cited.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I agree that the source should be cited in questions.  But that's because cites allow people to find the context of quotes.  Plagiarism is a serious charge of intellectual malfeasance, and we need to be sure that the elements of the crime exist before we make the accusation.  The essence of plagiarism is fraud.

Comment: Point taken @deadrat, and there was no accusation meant.  I'm sure no one here is intending to commit plagiarism and any oversight is unlikely to result in any formal accusation but the fact is that regardless of the purpose of citing sources, we can't intuit the OP's reasons for omitting the citations so it's just good practice to include them.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I suppose I should stop talking past the close or at least take this to chat.  You're the second person with whom I've had this unsatisfactory discussion, so maybe I'm the one out of step.  Plagiarism is a strict liability offense:  intent doesn't matter, only the presentation of another's work as your own.  We don't need to intuit the OP's reasons.  We need only ask whether anyone would think that Jarl has presented any or all of the five quotes as his own.

Comment: My guess is that they are from five different sources.  #4 is probably from a political rival of William Pitt the Elder (1708 - 1778) or William Pitt the Younger (1759 - 1806) and means that Pitt thinks he is God.  Why has no one proposed closing this question?  I am very tolerant, but this seems too much like being asked to do homework.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez I have to express my apologies to you since the sources of these sentences are not been cited. It's not because I want to present these sentences as my own, but because I just don't know their sources. I came across them in one of my English textbooks which is not written in English. Without any explanations or annotations, the sentences seem to be unintelligible. It's difficult for me to understand them as English is not my mother tongue. Could you please give your interpretations of these sentences? Thank you.

Comment: @deadrat Assuredly these sentences are not written by me. They are in one of my coursebooks which is not written in English. Thank you for you advice. I will present the sources if I can. Now could you please give your interpretations of these sentences?

Comment: @Jarl:  #4 I am pretty sure is that Pitt thinks he is God. (the clue is the phrase "the word".)  Both Pitt the Elder and Pitt the Younger were British Prime Ministers.  #5 is a less strong version of "Behind every great fortune is a great crime", which is a well-known statement of Balzac;  Colin Fine (below) has nailed #1 and also #5 and done a good job on #3.   I don't think we have got #2 quite right yet.  I assure you, no one thought you were the author, or thought you were a plagiarist.

Comment: @Jarl, we pretty much figured the sentences weren't yours but you can mention the textbook as the source.  (No apology necessary!) 

Comment: @ab2 Thanks a lot for your information! It's been a great help. But what's the nuance between "a word" and "the word"? What exactly can you infer from the definite article or indefinite artile? And what's the meaning of the "word" here? Is it interpreted as "a promise", "a single word of vocabulary" or "remarks, statemens or something that has been said"? I am rather confused.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez The direct source is "Toward Better Comprehension and Expression in English" published by Peking University. You can find the sentences in the free trial reading part provided by the Amazon Bookstore online if you'd like to. All these five sentences are able to be read in the following webpage with a click of the picture. http://www.amazon.cn/%E9%AB%98%E7%BA%A7%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3%E4%B8%8E%E8%A1%A8%E8%BE%BE%E6%95%99%E7%A8%8B-%E5%AD%99%E7%91%9E%E7%A6%BE/dp/B00114KF0E

Comment: @Jarl  I'm not the best person to ask about religious things, but I think the word here refers to "The word of God".  More generally, now "the word", as in "Have you gotten the word about....?"  can mean just have you gotten the info about..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Art is about the individual; Science is about people working together.
2. There is always hope, unless we are truly in hell. But (the writer sees something limiting or unsatisfactory in hope) only in heaven could we be beyond (or above) hope.
3. Summer makes everybody special, or "royal".
4. (Difficult to interpret without context, but I suggest:) I can always come up with a word that fits; but Pitt can always find the very best word that fits.
5. ... I have seen few men get rich rapidly except by doing something that, if it were public, would embarrass them greatly.

Comment: For 2, I think the 2nd half is saying that there is always a need for hope until we are in heaven.

Comment: I think #2 can be reduced to "while we're alive" on both counts.

Comment: @Colin Fine  Great! Your paraphrases of the sentences are highly reasonable. Do you mind making further explanations of the 3rd sentence? Why does summer make everybody special? Is it because everyone wears various or beautiful clothes to show he or she is different?

Comment: @Robusto: I don't think that's all of it, because of the careful comparison of levels.

Comment: @Jarl. We cannot tell what specifically the writer had in mind about Summer. But I don't think it is about clothing.